# Is there a constructive approach to creating a distribution achieving the Chebyshev lower bound?

Tags: probability, distributions

I came across the following question and am wondering if there's a simple way to cook up a distribution achieving the Chebyshev lower bound:

Suppose $X$ has $\mu_X = \sigma^2_X = 9$. Define the lower bound for

$$\mathbb{P}[3 \leq X \leq 15]$$

Chebyshev tells us the answer is $\frac34$.

Can we come up with a specific distribution for $X$ that follows this?

More specifically, I'd prefer $X$ be discrete and restricted to take non-negative values.

A more general constructive proof would of course be more instructive!

Comment: Hint: examine a proof of the Chebyshev inequality.  It will indicate how to make it tight.

Comment: The explicit constructive proof that you desire can be found in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235548/6633) written by Moderator @Glen_b

Comment: Thanks @whuber. I first saw the continuous case; I don't think it's possible for it to bind if $X$ has support on any unbounded interval. The discrete case is simple enough, though.

Comment: Yep, the [limiting case is discrete](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235524/random-variables-for-which-markov-chebyshev-inequalities-are-tight/235548). You can keep it positive by a simple shift.