# An inequality giving a sharper bound than that given by the Chebyshev's?

Tags: references, probability-inequalities, inequality

Let $X > 0$ be a random variable; let $P$ be the underlying probability measure; let $\delta > 0$. I wonder if there is already in probability literature a known result giving a sharper bound for $P ( X > \delta )$ than that given by the Chebyshev's. (By Chebyshev's inequality I simply mean the relation $P(X > \delta) \leq \delta^{-1}EX$; one may call it Markov's inequality, which does not affect the discussion here.)

A major motive for this question is that, besides application convenience, there is a result in probability theory (in Chung's probability text, for example) stating that 
$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(X > n) \leq EX \leq 1 + \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}P(X > n)$. This is stunning, as if $X$ is integrable-$P$ then an upper bound for $P(X > n)$ in terms of $E X$ becomes "infinitely much" sharper than that given by Chebyshev's.

This triggers my interest as to if there is already a result that may be already well-known for probability theorists but somehow less known for applied probability people. If possible, I would love to be guided to the original and/or related literature.

Comment: (Deleted my previous answer because I realized it wasn't really an answer.) One point of note is that the inequality is at least tight for some cases; see e.g. [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235548/9964) which refers to it as Markov's inequality. So of course there is no bound which can _always_ be tighter.

Comment: You also might be aware of the continuous version of the stated inequality, that if $P(X \ge 0) = 1$, then
$$
E X = \int_0^\infty P(X > x) \mathrm{d}x
.$$
Of course in either the discrete or the continuous form, Markov's inequality gives a vacuous (infinite) bound here. I don't know of a general bound for $P(X > x)$ making the sum/integral converge.

Comment: What you are stating is markov's inequlality, chebyshev's inequality uses the variance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality.

Comment: @seanv507, I have a precautionary statement about this point. Chebyshev's inequality follows directly from Markov's inequality, so...

Comment: .... so just call it by what it is commonly called, which is Markov's, not Chebyshev's  (unless you have a particular reason not to, which you'd need to explain)

Comment: @Glen_b, Opinion has been noted. However, one point to be kept in mind is about the definition of "common" in your book. This argument is boring, which will lead to nowhere. If it is about a sense of authority, I recall that A. N. Shiryaev uses the term "Chebyshev's inequality". Would you ask him to explain the usage?

Comment: I simply seek better communication with your likely readers, not argument from authority. One person's usage (whether mine or yours or Shiryaev's) is neither here not there.

Answer (score 2):

Cantelli's inequality gives a better bound in many cases. Simply stated, for $k>0,$

$$P \left[X \geq \mu + k \sigma   \right] \leq \frac{1}{k^2+1} $$

For a thorough treatment, see B.K. Ghosh's "Probability Inequalities Related to Markov's Theorem," $\it{The \ American \ Statistician},$ August 2002, Vol. 56, No. 3, pp. 186-190.